# Loop through all elements of array inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I'm completely drawing a blank as to what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to query an array inside my mongoose model and I just can't seem to get it. I'm sure its something simple.

My model looks like this:

```
var aSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    userType: String,
    arr: [
        {
            id: Number,
            name: String, 
            description: String,
            attribute: String,
            answerType: String,
            textAnswer: String,
            skill: [
                {
                    heading: String,
                    detail: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to loop through all questions and print out the name for each record. I tried the following:

```
a.find({ "userType": "test" }, { "arr": 1 }, function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                console.log(users[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
```

I keep getting undefined for the name, how can I access the name of each element in my users array?

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.find({ "userType": "test" }, { "arr": 1 }, function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                console.log(users[i].arr[0].name);
            }
        }
    });
```

should work

Comment: Thanks, your answer pushed me in the right direction but I still needed to add the element number on the arr. 'users[i].arr[0].name. If you update your answer, I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: here you go ^_^